# slam gmapping for ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, python3, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wanted to know if the slam gmapping is available on ROS Noetic? I've tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-gmapping
```

And the terminal outputs:

```
Unable to locate package
```

When checking the ROS Wiki, I noticed that gmapping is still not available on Noetic, however, since this is a basic package, I wanted to know if there is any work around to get it.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356105/slam-gmapping-for-ros-noetic/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-06-30

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-30**:
I guess this is a similar situation as we had with Melodic. See #q327976 (and the linked #q300480.

> however, since this is a basic package

Please realise that gmapping and related packages have been `unmaintained` for a long time now. See also my comments about this in #q300480.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-gmapping

---

Originally posted by [BeepMaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/61556/beepmaster/) with karma: 56 on 2020-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4